# Can I get 3d array from 2d array using pandas?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, multidimensional-array

I want to get a 3d array from a 2d array.

So from here

```
U         A         B         C
0  1.438161 -0.210454 -1.983704
1 -0.283780 -0.371773  0.017580
2  0.552564 -0.610548  0.257276
3  1.931332  0.649179 -1.349062
4  1.656010 -1.373263  1.333079
5  0.944862 -0.657849  1.526811
```

I want to get here, where each table is another layer in the 3D array.

```
U         A         B         C
0  1.438161 -0.210454 -1.983704
1 -0.283780 -0.371773  0.017580
2  0.552564 -0.610548  0.257276

U         A         B         C  
1 -0.283780 -0.371773  0.017580
2  0.552564 -0.610548  0.257276
3  1.931332  0.649179 -1.349062

U         A         B         C
2  0.552564 -0.610548  0.257276
3  1.931332  0.649179 -1.349062
4  1.656010 -1.373263  1.333079

U         A         B         C
3  1.931332  0.649179 -1.349062
4  1.656010 -1.373263  1.333079
5  0.944862 -0.657849  1.526811
```

This is what I have, but it doesn't work as I intended

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import randn
df = pd.DataFrame(randn(6,3),columns=list('ABC'))

panel=[]
for i in range(4):
        data=df.head(3)
        panel.append(data)
        df.drop(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
panel = []
for i in range(df.shape[0] - 2):
    panel.append(df[i:i+3])
```